# Vector data linking

Tags: c++

I have a class Monsters and when a instance is created it should link each monster with there weapon.  ex. Gryphon monster should have gryphon attack 1 and gryphon attack 2 , of course the name of the attack is TBD, but for now well use gryphon attack 1 and 2.

Currenly I have this.

```
    #include <vector>

typedef enum {Living, Dead, Nature} Race;
typedef enum {Gryphon, Oracle, Mercenary,Templar,
              Satyr,Fallin Angel,ArcAngel,Satan,Grimreaper,
              Unbaptized Babies,Boggart,Succubus,Meat Wagon,
              Djinns,Manticore,Water Nymph,Plant Nymph,
              Mother Nature, Cannibal Tribesmen,Wyvern,
              Vegetable Lamb, Ent, Lava Worm, Alpha Dragon
              } MonsterType;
typedef enum {gryphon1,Oracle1, Mercenary1,Templar1,
              Satyr1,Fallin Angel1,ArcAngel1,Satan1,Grimreaper1,
              Unbaptized Babies1,Boggart1,Succubus1,Meat Wagon1,
              Djinns1,Manticore1,Water Nymph1,Plant Nymph1,
              Mother Nature1, Cannibal Tribesmen1,Wyvern1,
              Vegetable Lamb1, Ent1, Lava Worm1,Alpha Dragon1,
              Gryphon2, Oracle2, Mercenary2,Templar2,
              Satyr2,Fallin Angel2,ArcAngel2,Satan2,Grimreaper2,
              Unbaptized Babies2,Boggart2,Succubus2,Meat Wagon2,
              Djinns2,Manticore2,Water Nymph2,Plant Nymph2,
              Mother Nature2, Cannibal Tribesmen2,Wyvern2,
              Vegetable Lamb2, Ent2, Lava Worm2, Alpha Dragon2
              } Weapon;

Class Monsters{

protected:
    MonsterType type;
    Race race;
    std::vector<Weapon> weapon_list;
public:
     bool flying;
     bool lava;
     bool water;
     int life;
     int karmaCost;
     int move;
     int crit;
     int defMagic;
     int defNonMagic;
     bool isDead;
     bool canMove;
     bool canAttack;
     bool onFlag;
     int nextTurn;


};
```

I am not sure about the vector , nor if its needed it was just some experiments i was messing with..  But what is the best way to link the weapon to the monster? Also note each weapon has values that goes along with it,  So

```
gryphon attack 1 {
  int range = 10
  int ticks = 5
  bool magical = false
  int power = 23
  bool heals = false 
}  


gryphon attack 2 {
  int range = 5
  int ticks = 7
  bool magical = true
  int power = 29
  bool heals = true 
}
```

the actual values are read in from an ini or network, so not worried about the actual values yet, but i need to know i can add the values  `gryphon->weapon1->range = 5`

I am still very new to this so if something seems very wrong please tell me.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I'm going to attempt to answer "what is the best way to link the weapon to the monster?". Your use of `std::vector<Weapon> weapon_list` is pretty good, it reflects that Monsters can have multiple weapons, and that "has-a" relationships should be coded using [object composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition). I'd recommend making another class for Weapon, instead of the enum, then you could associate numbers to each weapon.

Comment: yes , that was the question. have have tired a few differnet ways but none seem to work, i think its more of not knowing the unknown then anything.

Comment: I would suggest that you start with a smaller list of different monsters to get the principles working first, then expand it. Then look at class hierarchy. You have a `class Monster`, which is a baseclass, and then from that you derive the different types of monster. Once you have a few variants, make a "factory" function that creates an arbitrary monster based on an `enum` or `string` input.

Comment: Sidenote: Use `enum Foo {…};`, not `typedef enum {…} Foo;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Speaking from experience: the approach you have chosen will lead to many problems in the future. I know I am not exactly answering your question, but I am doing it only to save you some trouble. Forgive me and/ord disregard this below if you want to do it your way.

Do not create specialized classes for each of your monsters or characters. Create a single, abstract, sort of compound class with many properties which describe various aspects of that game object. Sort of like that:

```
// simplified class declaration, not a C++ code
class GameActor {
  ActorVisualization visualization;

  vector<InventoryItems> inventory;

  ActorStatistics stats;

  vector<ActorEffects> appliedEffects;
}
```

Such abstract object will be used for all `Actors` in your game, including player characters.

The next step is to use the visitor pattern for all things that can happen to this actor.

```
// continued
class GameActor {
  bool applies(Visitor& visitor);

  void accept(Visitor& visitor) {
    if (applies(visitor)) {
      visitor.visit(this);
    }
  }
}

class Visitor {
  void visit(GameActor& actor);
}
```

Extend your `GameActor` to suit your needs if required. Whenever you are adding new functionaliy try to use the already implemented visitor mechanism. Create a new property of the `GameActor` only if necessary.

Samples of visitor? It could be written differently, but I hope it clarifies how things should get done.

```
class DamageInflictedVisitor {
  int amount;
  damageType_t dmgType;

  void visit(GameActor& actor) {
    double res = actor.getStats().getResistances().getResistanceForType(dmgType);
    int finalAmount = amount * (1-res);
    actor.getStats().inflictDamage(finalAmount);
  }
}

class ActorAliveVisitor {
  void visit(GameActor& actor) {
    if (actor.getStats().hp <= 0) {
      if (actor.getType() == AT_MONSTER) {
        // remove from the game, create a new ExperienceGained visitor applicable for players, etc.
      } else if (actor.getType() == AT_PLAYER) {
        // notify the game that the given player is dead
      }
    }
  }
}
```

By using such **simple** visitors you have very good code readability, you know what each visitor does simply by looking at it's name.

Comment: Iam not sure 100% i know what you mean,  But yes, i wont only 1 class "Monsters" thus in main i could do "addMonster(Gryphon)" and it would set all the data for that monster. I really like how your saying it and going to give this a try, but not sure ill get it working.

Comment: @GlenMorse this approach is a bit difficult to understand and even more difficult to utilize properly. But it is very flexible and versatile. Stick to abstraction and utilize the visitor well.

Comment: @GlenMores I extended the answer with samples

Comment: thanks, will try this... I think i understand with the full game , its each player has X monsters and each monster has x wepons.  and doing or i should say, setting it up like you have above is going to take me a few try. so if i dont accept right away, that is why

Comment: @glenMorse I didn't expect you to. Good luck!

Comment: I went with this, while i still had a friend help me on this, it did work and for that i thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a hierarchical structure for your monsters instead of a big typelist.
For example baseclass Monster which just has position/orientation and a race. then you make a derived class LivingMonster, which has health added for example, and a class LivingArmedMonster which has the weapon.
this will make sure you wont get a bloated class and makes it easier to add monsters later that use other functions without blowing up the big monster-class.

as for your weapon: the list is a great idea, only thing I would add is maybe use a pointer since then you can have different weapons (that are derived from base class: weapon) without changing the list.
also it will make it easier to exchange weapons between monster (you have a weapon storage which creates all the weapons) then you can drop and pick up the weapon, so you just move the pointer from 1 monster's weapon vector to the other.
this is way less intense than copying the full object

Comment: i am not sure haveing so many classes is good?  but any way i could see an example of this..

Comment: I dont know how big your game currently is, or how big it will be but it is definetly worth to keep this in mind as early as possible in development. because if you don't think about the architecture upfront you might run into trouble later causing you to have to refactor a lot. like I said it is more stated as an example of how to usually structure the code.. which is what you asked for I think

Comment: yes, currently the game has about 15 classes, just not sure if adding more for this is going to make it less or more confusing. But also i get what your saying, but i need a code example as thats what is confusing me how to code what you said..

Comment: The answer to the question should I create more classes is: If the behavior of the monsters is different then you should create more classes. It's not a good idea to have a method Update that has if statements that change what it does based on what type of monster it is. Also a bad idea for a walking monster to have a method fly() just because there is one god class that does all..

Answer (score 1):

```
Class Weapon {
  int range;
  int ticks;
  bool magical;
  int power;
  bool heals;
  public Weapon(int range, ......){
      this->range = range;
      ...
  }
};

Class Monster{
protected:
    MonsterType type;
    Race race;
    std::vector<Weapon> weapon_list;
public:
     int life;
     int karmaCost;
     ...
     void addWeapon(Weapon w){
         weapon_list.push_back(w);
     }
};

Class FlyingMonster : public Monster{
    public:
    int flightSpeed;
}


Class MonsterFactory{
   static FlyingMonster *CreateGryphon(){
      FlyingMonster *gryphon = new FlyingMonster();
      gryphon.addWeapon(WeaponFactory::CreateGryphonAttack1());
      gryphon.addWeapon(WeaponFactory::CreateGryphonAttack2());
      return gryphon;
   }
};

Class WeaponFactory{
   static Weapon* CreateGryphonAttack1(){
      Weapon* w = new Weapon(gryphonAttack1BaseRange);
      return w;
   }
};

FlyingMonster* tom = MonsterFactory::CreateGryphon();
tom->weapon_list[0].range = 50;
```